# group data by tolerance via index list

Tags: r, match, grouping

I dont know how to explain it shortly. I try my best: 
I have the following example data:

`Data<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,5,8,9,10),B=c(5.3,9.2,5,8,10,9.5,4),C=c(1:7))`

and a index

`Ind<-data.frame(I=c(5,6,2,4,1,3,7))`

The value in `Ind` corresponds to the `C` column in the `Data`. Now I want to start with the first `Ind` value, and find the corresponding row in the Data data.frame (column `C`). From that row I want to go up and down and find values in column A that are in a tolerance range of 1. I want to write these values into a result dataframe add a group id column and delete it in the dataframe `Data` (where I found them). Then I start with the next entry in the Index dataframe `Ind` and so an until the data.frame `Data` is empty. I know how to match my `Ind` with column `C` of my `Data` and how to write and delete and the other stuff in a for loop, but I dont know the main point, which is my question here:

when I have found my row in the `Data`, how can I look up fitting values of column `A` in the tolerance range up and below that entry to get my `Group` id?

what I want to get is this result:

```
A     B     C     Group
1     5.3   1      2               
2     9.2   2      2                 
3     5     3      2             
5     8     4      3          
8     10    5      1                 
9     9.5   6      1                
10    4     7      4
```

Maybe somebody could help me with the critical point in my question or even how to solve this issue in a fast way.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally: avoid deleting or growing a data frame row by row inside a loop. R's memory management means that every time you add or delete a row, another copy of the data frame is made. Garbage collection will eventually discard the "old" copies of the data frame, but garbage can quickly accumulate and reduce performance. Instead, add a logical column to the `Data` data frame, and set "extracted" rows to `TRUE`. So like this:

```
Data$extracted <- rep(FALSE,nrow(Data))
```

As for your problem: I get a different set of grouping numbers, but the groups are identical.

There might be a more elegant way to do this, but this will get it done.

```
# store results in a separate list
res <- list()

group.counter <- 1

# loop until they're all done.
for(idx in Ind$I) {
  # skip this iteration if idx is NA.
  if(is.na(idx)) {
    next
  }

  # dat.rows is a logical vector which shows the rows where 
  # "A" meets the tolerance requirement.
  # specify the tolerance here.
  mytol <- 1
  # the next only works for integer compare.
  # also not covered: what if multiple values of C 
  # match idx? do we loop over each corresponding value of A, 
  # i.e. loop over each value of 'target'?
  target <- Data$A[Data$C == idx]

  # use the magic of vectorized logical compare.
  dat.rows <- 
    ( (Data$A - target) >= -mytol) & 
    ( (Data$A - target) <= mytol) & 
    ( ! Data$extracted)
  # if dat.rows is all false, then nothing met the criteria.
  # skip the rest of the loop
  if( ! any(dat.rows)) {
    next
  }

  # copy the rows to the result list.
  res[[length(res) + 1]] <- data.frame(
    A=Data[dat.rows,"A"],
    B=Data[dat.rows,"B"],
    C=Data[dat.rows,"C"],
    Group=group.counter # this value will be recycled to match length of A, B, C.
  )

  # flag the extraction.
  Data$extracted[dat.rows] <- TRUE
  # increment the group counter
  group.counter <- group.counter + 1
}

# now make a data.frame from the results.
# this is the last step in how we avoid 
#"growing" a data.frame inside a loop.
resData <- do.call(rbind, res)
```

Comment: Note that this will not give an "optimal" grouping - there are packages for cluster analysis. But if this meets your needs, then that's good enough.

Comment: thank you again, which package would you recommend here?

Comment: I'd start with the "cluster" package and have a play with your data - see if any of the techniques offer a potential improvement. There are many more packages, with various specialties. See here: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html  And here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html

Comment: Thanks very helpful!